# Is it good to delete an unresolvable question?

Tags: discussion, questions, downvotes, vote-to-delete, unanswered-questions

Sometimes I asked some questions without actually any answers.

For example, a question:

> How do I batch rename variables with their suggested names in ReSharper?

This question, in fact, is **impossible** to have an answer, because ReSharper totally does not have this feature.

Then I **didn't get an answer and also some downvotes**.

---

I've been facing this situation several times. There is an option to flag a question as a **duplicate**, but not an option to flag a question as **unsolvable**.

With these **unsolvable** questions, the common thing that happens for me is some downvotes, no answer, and sometimes a comment to tell me it's impossible.

I would then notify my question may be **unsolvable**.

And I would consider to delete it, because I don't think an **unsolvable** question with (and cannot be with) an answer can contribute to the community, and it also slashes my reputation points to get downvoted.

---

But I don't know whether I **should** delete them. It is also said deleting too many questions may result in restrictions to post a new question.

What can I do facing this situation? Delete it? Or retain it? Or leave a comment, saying it may be **unsolvable**?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Actually "what you want to do is impossible" *is* an answer, and useful to anyone else searching for a way to do that impossible thing.